# Bootstrap form not working with django ( POST)

Tags: html, django, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a simple login mechanism while learning django and I have the view code right - it works with a simple form, but it doesn't work with this ( practically copy-pasted from the documentation ) Bootstrap and I can't figure out why. Specifically both ( for username and password) request.POST.get's return none.

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv = "X-UA-Compatible" contant = "IE = edge">
 <meta name = 'viewport' content = 'width = device-width, initial-scale = 1'>
 
 <title>title</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Minimal Blogging Platform">
  <meta name="author" content="MiBlo">
 {% load staticfiles %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
 <script src="{% static '/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
</head>
 
 
 
 
<body>
 <h1 align='middle' style="margin-bottom: 80px; margin-top: 80px;">Blogging made (very) minimal</h1>
 <form action = "/blog/login/" class="form-horizontal col-sm-offset-3" method='post'>{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="username" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Username</label>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Username" value="chuj">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="password" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
         <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
      </div>
    </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-4">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-4">
      <input type="submit" value="OK">
    </div>
  </div>
 <div class="form-group">
 <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-4">
  <a href="#">Register</a>
  </div>
  </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6):

It's easy. Both the `<input>` do not have `name` attribute, which is what will pass the values to the form.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Username" value="chuj" name="username" />
<input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" />
```

**Solution:** Add the `name` attribute to both of them.

```
name="username" />
name="password" />
```

The `id` attribute is only for identifying them using JavaScript on the client side. For a traditional form, it is the `name` attribute that's important than anything else. You don't even need to give the `id` in this case. Here, the `id` is just used for the `<label>` to work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `name` attribute inside the `input` field.

```
   <input type="text" name='username' class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Username" value="chuj">
  <input type="password" name='password' class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/#building-a-form

Comment: Umm... How is it different (or better) from my answer? Moreover the link you have quoted is like too complicated for any beginner to clearly say the usage of `name` attribute.

Comment: he posted the link to the documentation :D @PraveenKumar

Comment: @hansTheFranz Oh oh... Yeah, it's really very much required here... Thanks for clarifying! `:D`

Comment: @hansTheFranz `:facepalm:` `:sorry:`